# nextUntil() and childElements

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextuntil

the elements:

```
<div><input type="checkbox"></input></div> // <-- checked
<div><input type="checkbox"></input></div> // <-- checked
<div><input type="checkbox"></input></div> // <-- unckecked
<div><input type="checkbox"></input></div> // <-- checked
```

I want to use nextUntil() with the div-elemets to uncheck the boxes(child-elements) until box3 (first unchecked). Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkboxes being in different containers makes this rather complicated. The checkboxes in your example are NOT siblings to each other, which is why nextUntil (or rather prevUntil ) wont work here.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent().prevAll("div").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
```

That is assuming its not always the same checkbox that is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **[:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector instead:

```
$("div:lt(3)").find('input').prop('checked', false);
```

This will add `checked` property for `input` element inside `div` before `4th` position.

I used `3` here because `lt()` is 0-based index.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3D9J4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ( ! this.checked ) return false;
    this.checked = false;
});
```

**Note:** returning `false` from within the `each` callback breaks out of the loop.

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VCD94/